# Application displays blank page with url changing to /Account/Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

The application runs perfectly on existing server. Now we need to implement it on another server and this is where we keep getting blank page.

The only difference I could find was that existing server has Windows 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 whereas the new server runs on Windows 2012 with IIS 8.0. I have cross-checked the settings of IIS on both servers and they are identical.

Authentication mode is Forms.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" />
</authentication>
```

I would appreciate any help on this

Edit: Starting url is 11.0.2.1/MyApp. Instead of displaying login page it redirects to 11.0.2.1/MyApp/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fMyApp%2f and the page remains blank.

Comment: Could u clarify more by adding more details? Like add a screen or clarify on where and how the blank page is getting displayed.

Comment: In Server Manager, compare the installed services under the "Web Server (IIS)" role between the 2 machines.

Comment: @Darin I checked and Web Server settings are identical in Server Manager. Same components have been installed on both. I have checked in IIS and Authentication settings are same as well.

Comment: @Arcturus did you end up figuring this out? I think I have the same problem and I'm not getting much luck on Stack Overflow.